# How to prevent docker compose from timeout in ci in case of bad network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, docker-daemon

**Motivation**
because of reasons my gitlab-ci job times out during / towards the end of a docker compose up, which takes endless time (network, image size ...)

**Problem**
All the timeout settings don't have an effect; neither gitlab job timeout, nor docker compose timeout setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
[configuring the docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) helped.
In a dind scenario it is possible to inject configuration to the entrypoint, especially dramatically increasing the retries helped:

```
services:
      - name: docker:20.10.16-dind
        entrypoint: [
          "dockerd-entrypoint.sh", 
          "--max-concurrent-uploads=2",
          "--max-concurrent-downloads=2",
          "--max-download-attempts=20"
        ]
```